# Problems with built-from-source Ruby 1.9.2 on Linux, when using mkmf.rb

Tags: ruby, mkmf

I built Ruby 1.9.2-p320 on Fedora 16 with a vanilla ./configure command,
installing in /usr/local

The include files are in /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1

This program says "no":

```
require 'mkmf'
puts have_func('rb_thread_blocking_region') ? "yes" : "no"
```

I think it's because the command-line to build conftest.c to see if 
rb_thread_blocking_region exists doesn't include a -I path to the
various directories under /usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1, so the
build fails.  I'm not sure though, because mkmf uses a custom logger,
and anytime I try to add $stderr.puts statements to some of the
methods, I either don't see output, or I get that error message
telling me I need to install development tools.  I'm on linux with
a lot of dev tools in place, plus Ruby source, but if someone could
tell me how to dump the headers variable in the try_func method that
might be helpful.

The weird thing is I had no trouble building other binary gems
up to now, including RMagick, but I'm stuck on mysql2, as it
thinks that rb_thread_blocking_region doesn't exist, so it generates
incorrect code.

Digging in a bit more, I can compile this program with the appropriate
-I options, so rb_thread_blocking_region definitely exists.

```
$ cat conftest.c 
#include "ruby.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) { return 1; }

int t() {
  void ((*volatile p)());
  p = (void ((*)())) rb_thread_blocking_region;
  return 0;
}
```

Ahh, here's the problem, from mkmf.log:

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux 
    -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward  
    -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.  
    -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    
    -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses  
    -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers  
    -Wno-long-long conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib  
    -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/lib  
    -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../libcrypt.a(md5-crypt.o):  
    In function `__md5_crypt_r':
(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `NSSLOW_Init'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../libcrypt.a(md5-crypt.o):  
    In function `__md5_crypt_r':
```

I should've thought of that -- the crypt and openssl libraries have been a
hassle on Fedora.

Comment: I think you should be able to provide optional include dirs to the install procedure with something like `gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-include=/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1`.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.  I was able to build/install a local gem (0.2.11), but the gem was broken.  mysql2.rb requires 'mysql2/mysql2.rb', which doesn't exist.  I removed the gem, and running the suggested command resulted in the same problem:  "checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no"

Comment: You say you can build conftest with the appropriate options. What are the appropriate options you're using? Also isn't there an mkmf.log somewhere?

Comment: I can build conftest with -I's pointing to the two ruby include dir's, no big deal. I'm trying to understand why mkmf is failing by echoing the command used to build conftest. How do I use the logger for that?

Comment: Aren't you getting any errors when you install the gem? In most cases any error condition leaves behind a log files named `mkmf.log`. That's where all the output goes. Read your error message, in all cases I've seen it even tells you that you should read `mkmf.log`, and it tells you where the file is.

Comment: Summary: linker fails due on unresolved names in __md5_crypt_r

Comment: The output was misleading, because the reported failures are due to assuming rb_thread_blocking_region wasn't available. I forgot, always read mkmf.log when a build goes wrong.

Comment: I would post a new question now with proper tags. This question has morphed into something else and if you want the right people to pick it up post a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This evg I'll see what I need to install before bugging people. I'll close this question.

Answer (score -1):

Answer found by looking in mkmf.log.  Still not working, but that's another problem.